# AWS ECS jwilder/nginx-proxy fails to generate servers inside upstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am trying to setup [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) as reverse-proxy to proxy requests to various containers that expose the VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com environment variables.

The setup works if the container is started directly on the ec2 cluster host but fails with the following error: "error running notify command: nginx -s reload, exit status 1" if it is spawned from ECS.

The docker log of the container running the jwilder/nginx-proxy container:

`WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:43:37 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 4 containers
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:43:37 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:43:37 **Error running notify command: nginx -s reload, exit status 1**
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:43:37 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:43:37 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
2018/08/19 10:48:23 [emerg] 38#38: no servers are inside upstream in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:55
nginx: [emerg] no servers are inside upstream in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:55
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
dhparam generation complete, reloading nginx`

The environment is configured as the following:

```
services: 
- name: proxy
  *volumes*:
  Name: docker-socket
  Source Path: /var/run/docker.sock
  *containers*: 
    - name: proxy
      image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
      port: 80:80
      Mount Points:
        Container Path: /tmp/docker.sock
        Source Volume: docker-socket
        Read only: true 
- name: site
  *containers*:
    - name: site
      image: nginx
      port: 0:80
      environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com
```

Command to test:

```
curl -H "Host: example.com" localhost:80
```

It now returns the default nginx page because the nginx config file failed to generate a valid config because the upstream hosts are missing.

The generated invalid nginx config

```
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
  server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
  listen 80;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
  return 503;
}
# example.com
upstream example.com {
}
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 80 ;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example.com
  }
}
```

The proxy works as intended if the following command is used:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

If the command above is run it gives the following output:

`WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:18:48 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 10 containers
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:18:48 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:18:48 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2018/08/19 10:18:48 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
2018/08/19 10:19:09 [notice] 40#40: signal process started
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
dhparam generation complete, reloading nginx`

The generated valid nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
  server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
  listen 80;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
  return 503;
}
# example.com
upstream example.com {
        ## Can be connected with "bridge" network
      # ecs-site-site-add8hjasd
      server 172.17.0.3:80;
}
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 80 ;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
  }
}
```

My question is: why doesn't this work, is it because permissions or mount to the docker socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 days ago, Our team had met this question. We spent a lot of time for that.

Problem reason should be in AWS ecs-agent(we have 2 envrionment, one ecs-agent's version is 1.21 and another one is 1.24)

Yesterday, We solved this problem: Using AWS console to update ecs-agent to the latest version: 1.34 and restart the ecs-agent(docker contianer) Then the problem was solved.

Just paste this solution here. Hope it would be helpful to others!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's a good idea to avoid using domain names within your Nginx config, especially when defining upstream servers. It's confusing if nothing else.

Are all your values for `example.com` the same? If so you have an upstream block which defines an upstream server cluster with the name `example.com`, then you have a server block with a server name directive of `example.com` and then you are trying to proxy_pass to `example.com`.

Typically you specify an upstream block as a method of load balancing if you have several servers capable of handling the same request. Edit your upstream block and include all your upstream servers address:port, you can include other options to configure how Nginx distributes the load across them if you wish, see the Nginx docs for more info. The name you give to your upstream block is only used by Nginx and can be anything, don't use your domain name here. Something like:

`upstream dockergroup {`

Then add an ip address before the port in the `listen` directive in the server block and change the `proxy_pass` directive to `http://dockergroup`

I'm not sure of the specifics, but according to the docs on the page you linked:

> you can To add settings on a per-VIRTUAL_HOST basis, add your
>   configuration file under /etc/nginx/vhost.d. Unlike in the proxy-wide
>   case, which allows multiple config files with any name ending in
>   .conf, the per-VIRTUAL_HOST file must be named exactly after the
>   VIRTUAL_HOST.

The important issues to address are that your upstream block cannot be empty and the name of the upstream block should not conflict with any domains or hostnames on your network. From what I read you should be able to fix that using the various config options.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) But i am not sure if it solves my problem. I want to be able to have multiple containers running that listen for the same domain(example.com) and nginx-proxy should round-robin them. The nginx config gets generated by https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy so modifying it isn't an option

Comment: So multiple servers which can all handle the same requests?

Comment: yes, and all upstream servers should be the ips + ports of the running docker containers that specify an VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the update!, but i am still unsure if you fully understand the problem. The problem that https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy solves is that it uses the docker daemon to listen for new/destroyed docker containers, if a container is created it looks at the environment variables(VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com) of that container to determine what requests should be routed to this container. Because the changing containers it generates a new nginx config everytime a container is created or destroyed. Because of the dynamic config i can't edit the nginx config because it will be overridden.

Comment: I am afraid your solution won't be a viable solution because it involves changing a file that gets generated all the time. My problem is more a platform related problem. It works fine if you run all the docker containers on your own computer but fails when ECS launches them.

Comment: The link you posted has instructions which tell you how to configure changes which will be included each time the auto generated file is created

Comment: But i shouldn’t have to change any configuration because it works out of the box on my local machine. It seems to be AWS ecs related

Answer (score 0):

I have got this problem but in my case the Key reasons are - :

1. I did not register the `virtual_host` in `etc/hosts` -> that's one
   thing
2. The IP I am giving for another container must be in the same
   network of Nginx for proxy to that
3. Make sure the IP of a container to which you are proxy is
   working properly if it's an container IP then check the log by using
   Command `docker logs -f <container-name>`